# Identify parts I found in some kind of Star Wars set

Tags: set-identification

I found a ziplock bag with these parts in a drawer. I don’t know if it’s a full set or part of another set, but I see a lightsaber handle and a ship control panel in there.

[image: parts]

Answer (score 7):

A search for sets containing both [30387 brick 1 x 4 with hinges at both sides](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?P=30387) and [2 x 4 tile](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?P=87079) in yellow quickly yields set [75172 "Y-wing starfighter"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75172-1):

[image: set image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It looks like it is just the loading trailer from my son’s y-wing kit. Appreciate you figuring it out!